# Simple C double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C pointers and quite confused. I tried to search online but couldn't find any clear explanation. This is what I am trying to understand:

```
int x = 8;
int *ptr = &x;
int **dptr = ptr;
```

What does `**dptr` point to, `x` or `*ptr`? When I tried to print the content of `dptr` I found that it contains the address of `x` instead of `*ptr` but I am not sure why?

**Edited**

```
int x = 8;
int *p = &x;
int **ptr = &p;
int **dptr = ptr;
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You can't assign ptr to dptr. One is an int* and one is an int**.

Comment: you are right, I meant **ptr.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I assume you meant: `int **dptr = &ptr;` as `int **dptr = ptr;` is invalid.

```
int x = 8;
int *ptr = &x;
int **dptr = &ptr;
```

`dptr` points to `ptr` object.

`*dptr` points to `x` object.

`**dptr` is not a pointer but the `int` object `x`.

**EDIT**: question  was edited, `ptr` was an `int *` but seems to be an `int **` now...

Comment: Sorry, I meant int **ptr = &x and int **dptr = ptr.

Comment: @Programm-ist in that case it is invalid C. Did you mean `int **dptr = (int **) ptr`?

Comment: what about this then? int x = 8, int *p = &x, int **ptr = &p, int **dptr = ptr;

Comment: @Programm-ist then `dptr` has then the same value as `ptr` so `**dptr` is the same as `**ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 8;
int *p = &x;
int **ptr = &p;
int **dptr = ptr;
```

First, the value 8 is stored in `x`.

Next, with the statement

```
int *p = &x;
```

`p` will point to `x` ( that is , `p` now stores the address of `x` )

Next

```
int **ptr = &p;
```

Now `ptr` will store the address of `p`, which in turn stores the address of `x`

```
int **dptr = ptr;
```

`dptr` stores the address of `ptr` which in turn stores the address of `p` which points to `x`.

So, Now, `**dptr` will have the value of the integer `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the declarations

```
int x = 8;
int *p = &x;
int **ptr = &p;
int **dptr = ptr;
```

Then the following are true:

```
**dptr == **ptr == *p ==  x == 8  (int)
 *dptr ==  *ptr ==  p == &x       (int *)
  dptr ==   ptr == &p             (int **)
```